# Animated background when selecting ABTableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation, core-graphics

I've started implementing a custom subclass of ABTableViewCell.
All the cell rendition and so on is going just fine, but when the user selects a row I want it to change to another background color and then back again (as the user releases it) – and I would like it to be animated.

I've found answers to questions how to color the background, but that don't quite do it, as the change of the background color isn't being animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped using ABTableViewCell and instead subclassed UITableViewCell directly along with a custom LayoutSubviews (and let UIKit do the drawing).

Answer (score 0):

Well this will help U,

```
CGRect a=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100);

UIImageView *bImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];

bImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourBackGround.png"]; 

 [bImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

 cell.selectedBackgroundView=bImg;

 [bImg release];
```

Comment: And then use the UIImageView to perform the animation itself? :) I just want to animate from "normal background color" to "selected background color" (and then back again when "deselectRowAtIndedPath:animated:" is called).

Comment: I didn't find the above answer any helpful, since I think Parasanna misunderstood my question (which in turn may not have been the best ;) ). I skipped using ABTableViewCell and instead subclassed UITableViewCell directly along with a custom LayoutSubviews (and let UIKit do the drawing). Thanks anyway!